# Selenium Calendar: Months and Dates Selections: What i'm doing wrong

Tags: java, selenium

i'm trying to select Months and Dates from a calendar (www.booking.com) for practice purposes but i can not get it to select the month, if the month is into left panel. Probably i'm missing something. Can anyone give me a hint? or make an assist, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
   public void calendar() throws InterruptedException {


        String selectDate = "6/11/2020";
        Date d = new Date(selectDate);

        SimpleDateFormat years = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat months = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        SimpleDateFormat days = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        String year = years.format(d);
        String month = months.format(d);
        String day = days.format(d);
        String gap = " ";
        String search = month + gap + year;


        while (!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xp-calendar']/div/div/div/div/*[contains(@class,'bui-calendar__month')]")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='xp-calendar']/div/div/div[2]")).click();
        }


        int coutDays = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xp-calendar']/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).size();

        for (int i = 0; i < coutDays; i++) {
            String searchingDay = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xp-calendar']/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).get(i).getText();
            if (searchingDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day)) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xp-calendar']/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td")).get(i).click();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I see a lot of code, unexplained objects such as `By`, and no example data. Are you asking how to search a string for a portion matching the name of a month and a year? If so, give example date and delete the xpath distraction.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: What happens when the month is in the left panel? I don't see the code to open the date-picker ui as well.

Comment: @Kamal, from the left side, it picks date normally, the problem is when it reaches the last month of the calendar. As it begins all months pass from the left side, so it reads and selects normally, but at the last month that remains at the right side....it stacks.

Comment: @BasilBourque, i'm just learning and i'm new to Java and selenium so i didn't know that for time, eiterway it surten that i'm missing something and trying to figure out that is it

Comment: Please do not update your question with an answer, but post an answer to your own question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use the css to select the calendar date.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[data-date='2019-03-21']")).click();
```

Make sure you pass the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

Here is the code if you want to try in your console first.

```
document.querySelector('td[data-date="2019-03-21"]').click()
```

You don't have to open the date picker, just navigate to the page and run the above.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I will try it and I will respond

Comment: Found the solution: i used dynamic xpath to select months and dates, i post the code if anyone interested

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code:

```
String date = "10-June 2020";
String splitter[]= date.split("-");
String checkInMonth_Year = splitter[1];
String checkInDay = splitter[0];


List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='bui-calendar']/div/div/div/div"));

for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(a.get(i).getText());
    if (a.get(i).getText().equals(checkInMonth_Year))
    {
        List<WebElement> days = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='bui-calendar']/div/div/div["+(i+1)+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='bui-calendar__date']"));
        for (WebElement d:days)
        {
            if (d.getText().equals(checkInDay))
            {
                d.click();
                return;
            }
        }


    }
}
pauseFor1Sec();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'bui-calendar__control bui-calendar__control--next')]")).click();
calendar();
```